# Is the non-homogeneous and inhomogeneous linear ODEs means the same?

Tags: terminology, definition, calculus

Actually it's confusing me, somewhere it is written non-homogeneous and somewhere inhomogeneous.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about terminology.

Answer (score 4):

First let me say that “in homogeneous” and “non homogeneous” means the same thing. But I suspect you already know this.

A homogeneous differential equation is one where every term involves derivatives of the dependent variable and (though not necessary) terms containing the dependent variable itself. For example

$$\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} + \frac{d^2 f}{dy^2} + 7f =0$$

is called homogeneous.

A non homogeneous differential equation involves derivatives of the dependent variable with terms containing the independent variable(s). For example

$$\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} + \frac{d^2 f}{dy^2} + f = x^2 + xy$$

is a non homogeneous differential equation.

So if you hear your teacher/lecturer say “in homogeneous” and “homogeneous” or even “non homogeneous” do not be confused since he/she means the distinction between “homogeneous” and “non homogeneous”.

Comment: Not to be confused with a different meaning of "homogeneous" (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_first-order_differential_equations)), i.e. a first-order ODE that can be written in the form$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=F\left(\frac yx\right)$$